# Reading from file while re-writing the exact same data

Tags: unix, io, parallel-processing

Suppose I have two threads: first one is writing chunks of data to file using `pwrite`, second one is reading bytes from it using `pread`. Let's make 2 assumptions:

1) Reading thread can read a byte of file **if and only if** writing thread has already written something to it.

2) Writing thread never writes **different** data to the same byte of file, but it can occasionally **rewrite the exact same data it has written previously**.

Suppose reading thread reads some data in the same time writing thread rewrites it. Is it possible that reading thread will receive corrupted data in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any actual requirement for read/write atomicity under the conditions you describe.

First, from the POSIX [`write` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html), there are these two requirements:

> On a regular file or other file capable of seeking, the actual writing
>   of data shall proceed from the position in the file indicated by the
>   file offset associated with fildes. Before successful return from
>   write(), the file offset shall be incremented by the number of bytes
>   actually written. On a regular file, if the position of the last byte
>   written is greater than or equal to the length of the file, the length
>   of the file shall be set to this position plus one.

and appending to a file *is* atomic:

> If the O_APPEND flag of the file status flags is set, the file offset
>   shall be set to the end of the file prior to each write and no
>   intervening file modification operation shall occur between changing
>   the file offset and the write operation.

While that's not an explicit requirement for atomicity of *all* write calls, I can't imagine how a real-world file system could realistically be implemented in a way that would meet those requirements and not implicitly provide for atomic write calls.  If the transfer of the data and the update of the file offset have to be a combined atomic operation, that more than *strongly* implies the transfer itself has to be atomic.

Now, add in this *explicit* requirement:

> Write requests to a pipe or FIFO shall be handled in the same way as a
>   regular file with the following exceptions:
>
> ...
>
> - Write requests of {PIPE_BUF} bytes or less shall not be interleaved    with data from other processes doing writes on the same pipe. Writes of greater than {PIPE_BUF} bytes may have data interleaved, on arbitrary boundaries, with writes by other processes, whether or not the O_NONBLOCK flag of the file status flags is set.

That's seems to fit your needs, but that's **ONLY with respect to other write operations**.  Simultaneous read operations aren't mentioned at all.  And note well that even the `PIPE_BUF` atomic write requirement is limited by "shall not be interleaved with data from other processes".

There's nothing I'm aware of that says any read operation has to "see" the written data atomically.  The POSIX [read standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pread.html) states

> The standard developers considered adding atomicity requirements to a
>   pipe or FIFO, but recognized that due to the nature of pipes and FIFOs
>   there could be no guarantee of atomicity of reads of {PIPE_BUF} or any
>   other size that would be an aid to applications portability.

and

> I/O is intended to be atomic to ordinary files and pipes and FIFOs.
>   Atomic means that all the bytes from a single operation that started
>   out together end up together, without interleaving from other I/O
>   operations. It is a known attribute of terminals that this is not
>   honored, and terminals are explicitly (and implicitly permanently)
>   excepted, making the behavior unspecified. The behavior for other
>   device types is also left unspecified, but the wording is intended to
>   imply that future standards might choose to specify atomicity (or
>   not).

So, there's explicitly no requirement for atomicity of read operations.

But real-world implementations come in to play again.  Disks are block devices.  Files on disk are allocated in blocks.  The page cache is in page-sized blocks.  I can't see any way to do a write operation to any specific block of data that doesn't require that block to be locked while that data in that block is being updated.  So, as long as you stay within a single block of page cache (assuming a normal cached IO operation), I'd venture to say atomicity is almost certainly guaranteed.

But you'd be relying on implementation details - and even then only if you stayed within a single page in the page cache.  Cross page boundaries and even implementation specifics might fail to provide any attempt at atomicity across a write/read cycle.

Because of those implementation details, you'd likely *observe* atomic behavior - assuming small- to moderate-sized updates so that crossing a page boundary is unlikely.  And even then, crossing page boundaries will be done in order, and the first thread to lock page A is also likely to be the first thread to lock page B when an update crosses from page A to page B.  There's no guarantee that locking both page A and B for a *pending* write operations prevents read access to page B while only page A is actively being updated - that's again relying on implementation details - it *might* work.

So there's no real guarantee that I can see.

Look at it this way:  reads and writes of simple values such as `unsigned long` in *memory* aren't guaranteed to be atomic.

And that doesn't even address the fact that read and write operations aren't guaranteed to transfer all the requested data in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much for a profound response. Though it doesn't contain a direct answer to the question, it shows some new ways of thinking about specific bug I encountered.